# auc score in scikit-learn for no binary classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to calculate the `roc_auc` for different classifiers. Some are not binary classifiers. Here is a portion of the code I used:

```
if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
    y_score = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
else:
    y_score = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)

AUC=roc_auc_score(y_test, y_score)
```

However, I get an error for some classifiers (Nearest Neighbors
 for example):

```
ValueError: bad input shape
```

Just a remark, I used: `y_score = clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)`, but I don't really know if it's correct to use it.

Comment: ROC curves are only really defined in the binary case. It doesn't really make sense in the multiclass setting.

Answer (score 0):

okay so first things first

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

that will fit your model to your training data. first parameter being features, second parameter being target. okay, nicely done.

After fiting, you can apply ".predict" or ".predict_proba" on another dataset to get an estimative/prediction of its results. or you can do both fit and predict at the same time as you did below:

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
```

Now those are your predictions, not your score.
Your score will be a function of the prediction and the true value "(y_test)".
You can use different score metrics depending on the kind of problem you got, such as accuracy, precision, recall, f1, etc.. (read more at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

Now, roc_auc_score is one of those metrics, but you gotta watch out what you input that function, otherwise it wont work. As explained on the roc_auc_score page (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score), parameters should be:

**y_true:**  True binary labels in binary label indicators. 
**y_score :** Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

so, if you got labels, or multilabels for **y_true**, the function wont work, it gotta be binary. 
**y_score** in the other hand can be either binary or probabilities (ranging from [0,1])

hope that helps!

edit: if you got a multilabel problem, what you can do is tackle different classes one at a time. that way it will become many binary binary problems/models. (try building a model to predict if its class A or not, and do the roc curve of it, afterwards, move on to the next class and build another model, and so on)